# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{5/2}}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{5/2}}dx $$

it says to let $x = \tan(u)$ which i presume wants 
$$\frac{dx}{du} = \sec^2(u) =  $$
$$dx = \sec^2(u) du $$

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sec^2(u)}{(1+\tan^2(u))^{\frac{5}{2}}}du $$

now i know by trig identity that $1+\tan^2(u) = \sec^2(u)$

s0....

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1+\tan^2(u)}{(1+\tan^2(u))^{\frac{5}{2}}}du $$

and that's all i could get to

Comment: The obvious substitution is $x=\sinh t$.

Comment: You are using the trig identity in the wrong place. Change the denominator to $(\sec^2(\theta))^{5/2}$ instead of changing the numerator.

Comment: The bounds are wrong also. $x = 1$ would make $u = \pi/4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you correctly got to the point $$\int_{\backslash}^{\backslash} \frac{1+\tan^2(u)}{(1+\tan^2(u))^{\frac{5}{2}}}du $$ but you also know that $$1+\tan^2(u) = \sec^2(u)$$ so plug this equality into the integral above. You will get $$\int_{\backslash}^{\backslash} \frac{1+\tan^2(u)}{(1+\tan^2(u))^{\frac{5}{2}}}du  = \int_{\backslash}^{\backslash} \frac{\sec^2(u)}{\sqrt{(\sec^2(u)})^{5}}du \\ = \int_{\backslash}^{\backslash} \frac{\sec^2(u)}{\sec^5(u)}du \\ =  \int_{\backslash}^{\backslash} \frac{1}{\sec^3(u)}du \\ = \int_{\backslash}^{\backslash} \cos^3(u) $$ Now use the "peel off" trick by making the substitution $\cos^2(u) = 1-\sin^2(u)$. Then $$\int_{\backslash}^{\backslash} \cos^3(u) = \int_{\backslash}^{\backslash} \cos(u)(1-\sin^2(u)) \\ = \int_{\backslash}^{\backslash} \cos(u)-\cos(u)\sin^2(u) \\ = \left[\sin(u)-\frac{1}{3}\sin^3(u) \right]_{\backslash}^{\backslash} $$ I used the $\backslash$ throughout all the limits of integration because of the substitution $x = \tan(u)$. Now let's get our integral back to an equation in terms of $x$. Note that $\tan(u) = \frac{x}{1}$ so we can imagine a right triangle with opposite leg length $x$ and adjacent leg of length $1$. This means the hypotenuse of our triangle will be $\sqrt{x^2+1}$, and hence $\sin(u) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$. Thus,  $$ \left[\sin(u)-\frac{1}{3}\sin^3(u) \right]_{\backslash}^{\backslash} = \left[\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}-\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)^3 \right]_{0}^{1} $$

Comment: Why would you need to put it back in terms of $x$ when you can just  substitute the bounds? $x = 0$ to $1$ gives $u = 0$ to $\pi/4$.

Comment: Both ways get you the same answer. However my way offers OP a chance to practice trig sub, which is very useful when dealing with integrals.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sec^2(u)}{(1+\tan^2(u))^{\frac{5}{2}}}du=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sec^2(u)}{(sec^2(u))^{\frac{5}{2}}}du=\int_{0}^{1} cos^3(u)du=\int_{0}^{1} (1-sin^2(u))(cos(u))du$$

Answer (score 0):

i think $x=\tan(u)$ works also since $1+x^2=1+\tan(u)^2=\frac{\sin(u)^2+\cos(u)^2}{\cos(u)^2}=\frac{1}{\cos(u)^2}$